# Why client cert is not sent during SSL connection? CXF 2.7.9

Tags: java, ssl

## Background

My application is deployed in jboss 5, communicates with a Web service server which requires MASSL. (2-way SSL)

## Issue

By looking at the log of SSL connection, client cert is not sent even it has been loaded at the beginning.

Log details as below, **client cert is supposed to be sent after server hello is done**.

**[EDIT]** Added more details based on reply

1. added **CertificateRequest** in log
2. Cient certificate actually matches above request - (a) algorithm is RSA, (b) signed by one the CAs speficied in the request

logs:

```
2016-11-25 09:32:38,434 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) keyStore is : /XX/XX/my.jks
2016-11-25 09:32:38,434 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) keyStore type is : jks
2016-11-25 09:32:38,434 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) keyStore provider is :
2016-11-25 09:32:38,434 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) init keystore
2016-11-25 09:32:38,440 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) init keymanager of type SunX509
2016-11-25 12:00:04,420 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) ***
2016-11-25 12:00:04,421 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) found key for : mykey
2016-11-25 12:00:04,432 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=xx.xxx.xxx.com, OU=xxxxxxxx, O=xxxx, L=xxxx, ST=xxx, C=xx
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

 Issuer: CN=abc AD Object CA1, DC=core, DC=dir, DC=def, DC=com

...

2016-11-25 12:00:05,520 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) *** CertificateRequest
2016-11-25 12:00:05,521 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) Cert Types:
2016-11-25 12:00:05,521 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) RSA
2016-11-25 12:00:05,521 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) Cert Authorities:
2016-11-25 12:00:05,521 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) <CN=abc AD Object CA1, DC=core, DC=dir, DC=def, DC=com>
2016-11-25 12:00:05,521 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) <CN=abc Policy CA1, O=gh Corporation Limited>
2016-11-25 12:00:05,522 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) <CN=abc Root CA>

2016-11-25 09:32:39,475 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) *** ServerHelloDone
2016-11-25 09:32:39,475 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) *** Certificate chain
2016-11-25 09:32:39,475 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) ***
2016-11-25 09:32:39,482 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) *** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
2016-11-25 09:32:39,482 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) http-0.0.0.0-8080-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 269
2016-11-25 09:32:39,482 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) SESSION KEYGEN:
2016-11-25 09:32:39,483 INFO  [STDOUT] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-4) PreMaster Secret:
```

## question

Did I missing something here?

Comment: I guess that a certificate that matches the constraints expressed in the CertificateRequest couldn't be found. Note that the client is sending an empty `CertificateChain`.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that. That's where the client sends the certificate and now it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having same issue while using **CXF (2.7.9)**, this is a doggy issue that CXF introduces.

CXF doesn't pick up keystore configured by VM argument "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore", but has its own solution. see http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-ConfiguringSSLSupport

Answer (score 1):

> client cert is supposed to be sent after server hello is done.

No it isn't. It is only supposed to be sent if:

- the server has requested it, with a `CertificateRequest` message
- the client has a certificate which is signed by one of the CAs specified by the server
- the client has a certificate which matches the certificate types specified by the server.

There is no evidence in your question that all these condtions apply.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've updated my question with answers.